# SELECT statement with fetch_array in mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I always find it difficult to write MySQLi prepared statements, because many functions work differently than in the old way. Right now I am facing a problem regarding `fetch_array()`.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT category_id FROM post_items Where user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
$result = $stmt->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you are trying to fetch the results by

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

which is not the case. as [execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) will return you only a boolean value.

do it like.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT category_id FROM post_items Where user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //result is in row
}
```

Comment: work like a charm thx! so my mistake is assuming execute() returned result right? so I need to use get_result(). is get_result() same as query()?

Comment: no its replacement for binding result step. else you should do a `bind_result` i guess.

Comment: what is get_result() do? I got the same result returned by $result = $db->query($query).. why??

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt->execute();` doesn't return result. You need `$stmt->get_result();`.

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT category_id FROM post_items Where user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
foreach($result as $row) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

replace this:

```
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
```

by this

```
  $stmt->bind_result($category_id);

  while($stmt->fetch()){
       $myArray=$category_id;
  }
```

Comment: but mithunsatheesh method is working, can please explain more?

Comment: both ways are right, my way you're binding the result of stmt to a variable, then fetching stmt and using the variable you binded to.